# Validating datetime entries in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I'm playing with database and model in Rails, and I have a 'create tours' migration that looks like this

```
class CreateTours < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :tours do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :price
      t.datetime :starts_at
      t.datetime :ends_at
    end
  end
end
```

I added a model `Tour`

```
class Tour < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true,
                   uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :starts_at, presence: true
  validates :ends_at, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true,
                         numericality: { greater_than: 0 }

  validate :end_time_is_valid

  def end_time_is_valid
    error_msg = 'Trip cannot ends before it began'
    errors.add(:ends_at, error_msg) if ends_at < starts_at
  end
end
```

And I added RSpec

```
RSpec.describe Tour do
  subject do
    described_class
      .create(
        name: 'Tour 1',
        starts_at: Time.zone.now,
        ends_at: Time.zone.now + 7200,
        price: 200
      )
  end

  let(:invalid_flight) do
    described_class.create(
      name: 'Tour 2',
      starts_at: Time.zone.now,
      ends_at: Time.zone.now - 7200,
      price: 200
    )
  end

  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:starts_at) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:ends_at) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:price) }

  it { is_expected.to have_many(:bookings) }
end
```

Now, I'm getting an errors like

```
Flight should validate that :starts_at cannot be empty/falsy
     Failure/Error: errors.add(:ends_at, error_msg) if ends_at < starts_at

     ArgumentError:
       comparison of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with nil failed
     # ./app/models/tour.rb:18:in `<'
     # ./app/models/tour.rb:18:in `end_time_is_valid'
     # ./spec/models/tour_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

What I'm trying to add is a validation that the end tour time cannot be before start tour time.

But the custom validation fails, and I'm not sure why.

I'm playing with Rails and I'm not sure how should I do this.

I'm using `shoulda-matchers` for testing.

Some simple models like `User`, which just has simple `name` and `email` validation is passing (no custom validations).

How do I validate this? Should I use `numericality` here as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your validation is still invoked when `starts_at` is blank/nil, even though you've defined a `presence` validation: there's no hierarchy to the validations, so one failing can't cause others to be skipped.

Consequently, your validation method should just skip the check if either value is blank -- leaving the `presence` validation to record the error.

```
def end_time_is_valid
  return if starts_at.blank? || ends_at.blank?

  error_msg = 'Trip cannot ends before it began'
  errors.add(:ends_at, error_msg) if ends_at < starts_at
end
```

Comment: I'll try this and see what it returns. I thought that order of validation is not important when specifying them in the model.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick! Thanks. I think I assumed that if the presence fails, the other validation will automatically be skipped since no DB entry will be made.